# Match Values in Excel and compute a formula

Tags: excel

[Player Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAPWD.png)
[Team Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fHYG.png)
[Example Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0MnB.png)

Currently I have two tables: The first, with all player data in the basketball conference (Pts, Ast, BLks, Rebs, etc) and the second, with all the team data in the conference (Pts, Ast, BLks, Rebs, etc) the difference being the team table is the totals for the complete team. In a separate table I would like to be able to compute some additional values for each player based on both his basic stats and the teams total stats. In order to do this I believe I need to match first a player to a team using a team Name column and if the player's team name matches the team name totals then use corresponding values in the rest of the columns within that team name row. Then repeat this for each player in the conference.

I have tried using the MATCH and INDEX but do not believe they are what I am looking for as once I match the team names I need to use the entire rows worth of data within a formula.

Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you expect your third new table to look like? a player stats are in a row or column? A picture of what you already have could do the job.

Comment: And the answer is yes, you'd use `MATCH` and `INDEX`

Comment: Hi thanks for your response as this is the first question I have asked, I just edited my original post to include pictures of each table.

Comment: Hi bulzy22, welcome to stack overflow. Can you please provide an example of expected outcome (or rather in your case, an example of a calculation you would be performing from both tables). It also wouldn't hurt to show some work

Comment: " I would like to be able to compute some additional values for each player based on both his basic stats and the teams total stats" this part specifically is a bit ambiguous and could mean a lot of things.

Comment: HI soulshined, I edited my post to include an example outcomes picture. I have been able to in another excel doc perform this calculations for individual teams my issues now is trying to make the process easier my performing the calculations for all team at the same time

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I wouldn't create a new table for that, just add the new data you want in new columns in the players table. That way you can do this:

If your new data's column headers have the same order as the column headers you're extracting data from of the teams table, then Calculate `d` and put this formula in the first cell in the first new column you added to the players table, and copy it to the rest of the table.

`=INDEX(TeamsTable, MATCH(TeamsColumnInPlayersTable, TeamsColumnInTeamsTable, 0), COLUMN() + d)`

Where `d` is the difference between the column number of the cell you're adding this formula to and the column number of the of the column you want the data extracted from in TeamsTable.

For example, if you want to add new data in columns(E, F, G, H) in the players table, and these columns are extracting data from columns (L, M, N, O) in teams table respectively, then `d = Num(L) - Num(E) = 12 - 5 = 7`.

However, if they're not in the same order then your formula becomes this:

`=INDEX(TeamsTable, MATCH(TeamsColumnInPlayersTable, TeamsColumnInTeamsTable, 0), col)`

Where `col` is the number of the column that has the data you want extracted from. Put this formula in the first cell of each new data column and copy downward.